# Is there any property to define failed mapper threshold

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

By default if a mapper/reducer fails, hadoop tries to run other instance of it and if it fails 4 times(default value) hadoop marks complete MR job as failed.

I am processing some raw data and i am ok if MR job fails to process 30% of data. is there any configuration by which I can set if 30% of mappers fail don't kill the job and give output of remaining 70% of data. I can handle exceptions in my code and maintain failed and success records in counter but i want to know is there any such config in hadoop

Comment: [Skipping Bad Records](https://www.inkling.com/read/hadoop-definitive-guide-tom-white-3rd/chapter-6/task-execution#ef742852835568b3b0d695686f52642c) may be helpful for you. But now there is no such threshold.

Comment: Another solution would be use your own counter to count % of failures. Use try-catch block to capture error and increment your counter in the catch block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks! I got the answer from definitive guide.

> For some applications, it is undesirable to abort the job if a few
>   tasks fail, as it may be possible to use the results of the job
>   despite some failures. In this case, the maximum percentage of tasks
>   that are allowed to fail without triggering job failure can be set for
>   the job. Map tasks and reduce tasks are controlled independently,
>   using the mapreduce.map.failures.maxpercent and
>   mapreduce.max.reduce.failures.percent properties.