# Allow more than one hadoop/EMR tasks to fail before shutting down

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, hadoop-streaming, elastic-map-reduce

I'm trying to use hadoop on Amazon Elastic MapReduce where I have thousands of map tasks to perform.  I'm OK if a small percentage of the tasks fail, however, Amazon shuts down the job and I lose all of the results when the first mapper fails.  Is there a setting I can use to increase the number of failed jobs that are allowed?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the answer for hadoop:

[Is there any property to define failed mapper threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466503/is-there-any-property-to-define-failed-mapper-threshold/19231200#19231200)

To use the setting described above in EMR, look at:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html#PredefinedbootstrapActions_ConfigureHadoop

Specifically, you create an xml file (config.xml in the example) with the setting that you want to change and apply bootstrap action:

./elastic-mapreduce --create \
--bootstrap-action s3://elasticmapreduce/bootstrap-actions/configure-hadoop \
--args "-M,s3://myawsbucket/config.xml"